# Effusion of particles from one box to another - pressure calculation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

Suppose we have a container divided into equal halves. Right half is fixed at temperature $T$, volume $\frac{V}{2}$.

Initially it has pressure $P_0$, a hole of area $A$ is opened between them. I have to show that the pressure in the right half is:

$$ p = \frac{p_0}{2} \left[ 1 + exp \left(-\langle v \rangle\frac{A}{V}t \right) \right] $$ where $\langle v \rangle$ is average speed of molecules in right half.

I got an answer that's very very close, but off by a factor of $2$ in the exponential!

**Attempt**

$$ dN = -A\phi_{(t)} dt  $$

Using flux $\phi = \frac{1}{4} n\langle v \rangle $,

$$dN = - \frac{A}{4} n \langle v \rangle dt = -\frac{A}{4}\left( \frac{N}{V/2} \right) \langle v \rangle  dt  = -\frac{NA}{2V} \langle v \rangle dt $$

The graph looks something like this: [image]

We solve for the dotted graph, then translate upwards by $\frac{N_0}{2}$.

Integrating, and translating upwards i get: $ p = \frac{p_0}{2} \left[ 1 + exp \left(-\langle v \rangle\frac{A}{2V}t \right) \right] $

Not sure why I'm missing a factor of $2$..